# Deleting Spaces In Complicated Strings

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexof

Just another silly novice question (like  Confucius said it is better to ask then live in ignorance) regards to deletion of spaces in long and complicated strings. First of all I must say that I am trying to do exercises from the book: C# 7.0: All-In-One-For-dummies and the following example I took from this book. Here is the code:

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string someString = " this is a\nstring. ";
            char[] whiteSpace = {' ', '\n', '\t' };
            Console.WriteLine("Here is how the string looks before:" + someString);
            Console.WriteLine("And here is how it looks after: ");
            for( ; ; )
            {
                int offset = someString.IndexOfAny(whiteSpace);
                if (offset == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                string before = someString.Substring(0, offset);
                string after = someString.Substring(offset + 1);
                someString = string.Concat(before, after);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(someString);

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to terminate the program. ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Output is like this: "thisisastring" But why? Can anybode explain it?
Everything looks quite understandable for me until the line with two substrings ("before" and "after") being concatenated after. Why infinite loop deletes all spaces? Substring() method deletes nothing as far as I know and Concat() too. Variable "before" is the just the part before the space and variable "after" is the part after the space. In which moment program deletes space?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: If `before` is the part before the space, and `after` is the part after the space, and you join the two together (with `Concat`)... what do you get?

Comment: There *is no delete* happening.  [`string.Substring(int, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32)) returns "A string that is equivalent to the substring that begins at startIndex in this instance, or Empty if startIndex is equal to the length of this instance."

Comment: Are you aware that all the methods on string do not modify the string they are called on; they return a new string with the modification applied. strings cannot be changed; you have to make new ones. `var s = "hello world"; s.Replace("hello", "goodbye");` - s is still "hello world". The Replace operation returned a new string "goodbye world" but it wasn't stored anywhere

Comment: Also be aware that this will throw if the last char in the string is in `whiteSpace`.

Comment: Most of your questions can probably be answered by using the debugger. Please read the "how to use the debugger" chapter in your book as a priority. Learning to use it effectively will probably be the single most productive thing you can don on your c# journey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain:

```
...
// Infinite loop; common alternative form is "while (true) {...}" 
for( ; ; )
{
    // looking for the leftmost index of any char from whiteSpace array
    int offset = someString.IndexOfAny(whiteSpace);
    
    // if no whitespace found ...
    if (offset == -1)
    {
        // ... stop processing the string
        break;
    }
    
    // from now on offset is the index of the leftmost whitespace character 

    // we remove leftmost whitespace character: someString = before + after
    // note, that before is a substring before whitespace; 
    // after is a substring after whitespace

    // before - we take all characters in [0..offset) range; 
    // note, that char at offset index - i.e. whitespace character - is excluded
    string before = someString.Substring(0, offset);

    // after - we take all characters starting from offset + 1 -
    // again we don't take whitespace character  which is at offset index 
    string after = someString.Substring(offset + 1);

    // finally, we combine all characters except the leftmost whitespace,
    // i.e. character which is on offset index
    someString = string.Concat(before, after);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The program doesn't "delete space" physically. This line:

```
someString = string.Concat(before, after);
```

Does two things:

1. Take the before and after substrings and concatenate them, obtaining a new value of type string (the value returned from the Concat function).
2. Make an assignment of that new value to the existing string variable someString. Hence, the previous value stored in someString (which contains spaces) is discarded, and replaced by this new value.

Answer (score 0):

The `before` string is the string before the whitespace character and the `after` string is the string after the whitespace character, and both of them exclude the whitespace character, so the new string is the same as the previous with the whitespace character cut out. That is why the end result doesnt have any whitespace characters.

Comment: Thank you guys for very clear explanations! I do understood. My problem was that I’ve managed to forget that the second parameter of Substring() method actually means the LENGTH and NOT an index position. That’s why code made no sense to me.